# Does CO2 laser treatment work well with acne scars?

Tags: dermatology, laser

Several dermatologists says that CO2 laser treatment is still the best solution for acne scars. Does CO2 laser treatment provide a smooth skin or just mitigate these scars? What are the side effects of this treatment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CO2 laser treatments work by vaporizing the damaged skin cells. After the procedure, you will need to take medication to reduce swelling in your eyes, but you can also ease the swelling by elevating your head when sleeping. You will be itchy for 12-72 hours after the procedure. For the next week, your skin will get dry and peel. Your face will also be red for 2-3 months after the procedure. Other side effects are burns from the laser, scarring, and changes in your skin's pigmentation.

#### Is it worth it?

It can cost upwards of $2000, but it does seem to work. The burning or scarring from the laser are unlikely, so it is up to you to decide. If you want more reviews go [here](http://www.realself.com/CO2-laser/info).

---

<sup>[WebMD - Laser Resurfacing](http://www.webmd.com/beauty/laser-skin/laser-resurfacing?page=1)</sup>